# Duplicate key value violates unique constraint in Postgres

Tags: postgresql

I have setup a table like so

```
CREATE TABLE teams
(
  ID SERIAL PRIMARY KEY,
  league_name VARCHAR,
);
```

When running an insert I get the error `duplicate key value violates unique constraint "teams_pkey"`

My insert looks like

```
async function saveMissingTeamData(teamObject) {
  let response;
  try {
    response = await pool.query('INSERT INTO teams (league_name) VALUES ($1) RETURNING *', [teamObject.league_name]);
  } catch (e) {
    console.error('Error Occurred in saveMissingTeamData', e);
    throw e;
  }
  return response.rows;
}
```

I was under the impression (could be wrong) that by specifying `SERIAL` then auto incrementation of the id would be handled by psql?

What's strange is that it will work on my production environment but not on my staging environment (which is a copy of lives data)

How can I rectify this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that, for some hard-to-discover reason, the sequence associated with the column `id` does not match the actual contents of the column. You can fix it with this one-time intervention:

```sql
select setval('teams_id_seq', coalesce((select id+ 1 from teams order by id desc limit 1), 1), false);
```

Read about [Sequence Manipulation Functions.](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-sequence.html)